# How to redirect ourdomain.ch/index.php?xyz to ourdomain.ch?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Due to a past hacking of the site we have hundreds of indexed files in Google (site:ourdomain.ch) like this:

ourdomain.ch/index.php?02374234999
ourdomain.ch/index.php?wer99234234

1) These URL's are not redirected and show the content of the homepage, just with another URL (see above). I guess this is a problem SEO wise, i.e. **duplicate content**. Right?

2) I am not able to redirect these files to the root. No way what i do. I added that line to the existing .htaccess:

> RewriteRule ^index.php\?123 /index.php [R=301,L]

just to test it with ourdomain.ch/index.php?123
it redirects to: ourdomain.ch/?123. Not what i want...

Updated .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php\?123 /index.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any hint how to accomplish that?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Cheers,
Cesare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php? [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect `/index.php?foobar` to `/index.php` removing the querystring from your index.php .

Comment: thanks for your help but its not working properly. it redirects but not to index.php but instead e.g. ourdomain.ch/?123
ourdomain.ch/index.php?123 --> ourdomain.ch/?123.

Comment: @cesare This should redirect to `/index.php` . Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: your were right. why is there a ? after /index.php: RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php? [L,R=301]. i don't understand that.

Comment: @cesare the `?` at the end of the redirect destination discards the old querystring from your new url otherwise without this your new url will look something like `/index.php?querystring` .